# How to trace file access with dtrace on solaris

Tags: solaris, dtrace

I would like to find out how can I trace (show) file access on Solaris.
I already found the [dtrace toolkit](http://www.brendangregg.com/dtracetoolkit.html) in a hope that `voptrace` will fit the bill. I ran it with `voptrace -t /my/path` if I `ls` or `cat` files under that path it produces no output. Am I looking at the wrong tool? Can someone suggest another one to find a solution?

**UPDATE**
@bahamat

Okay, it was giving error messages like this:

`dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 3 (ID 126: syscall::openat:entry): invalid address (0xffd19652) in predicate at DIF offset 28`

After redirecting stderr it seems it actually gives quite close to what I want.

Comment: Check here: http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/DTrace_Topics_One_Liners#Files

Comment: Are you tracing within a zone? That error comes up when there's an event at a memory address that the running process doesn't have permission to read. Usually because of reduced capabilities within a zone.

Comment: @bahamat I was doing testing from a zone so that makes sense. Thx.

Answer (score 10):

Brendan Gregg has a number of good `dtrace` one liners [on his site](http://www.brendangregg.com/DTrace/dtrace_oneliners.txt). Among them, this one liner to watch files opened by process:

```
dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry { printf("%s %s",execname,copyinstr(arg0)); }'
```

Expanding that, you can watch a particular file being opened by adding a predicate:

```
dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry /copyinstr(arg0)=="/etc/passwd"/ { printf("%s %s",execname,copyinstr(arg0)); }'
```

Yielding the following output:

```
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  2  12622                     open64:entry cat /etc/passwd
```

`ls` is slightly different, in that `ls file` doesn't open `file`. It uses `stat` instead (specifically, `lstat64`) so the probe would be `syscall::*stat*:entry`.

---

Note that `dtrace` implementations vary. The commands above were run on illumos. YMMV.

Comment: The only question is: will this detect if a long running process had the file already opened when dtrace started?

Comment: No, `dtrace` probes fire *as events happen*. You can't use dtrace for something in the past. To see which processes *currently* have a particular open, on illumos I use `fuser <file>` or `lsof -f -i <file>`.

Comment: Addition: You can end up with `error on enabled probe ID 4 (ID 968: syscall::open_nocancel:entry): invalid address (0x...) in predicate at DIF`. Here's the error explained and a solution: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5488/gcgkk/index.html (search for `Avoiding Errors`)

Comment: Addition 2: You can also replace the predicate with `/strstr(copyinstr(self->file), "passwd") != NULL/` to match relative/absolute path names.